# Closure compiler trips up on "final" keyword

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am using close to compile JavaScript using Google' closure compiler. The bundle I am compiling uses a lot of packages imported by NPM, and one of the downstream dependencies uses the `final` keyword. This is apparently a reserved keyword in ES3, and as a result closure throws an error.

What is the way around this? I don't want to change all the dependencies to not use `final`. Im a using Babel in the transpilation pipeline, if that makes a difference.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es3-memeber-and-property-regenerator

Comment: I assume this is a property reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--language_in` flag to specify an input language of ECMASCRIPT5 or higher.